# MKAnnotationView Default Callout Opacity

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, opacity, mkannotationview, callout

I'm using MKAnnotationView for pins & callouts and I realize that there is the option to create a custom callout with a custom animation which I may end up doing if it's my only choice...  However does anyone know if there is a way to simply alter the default opacity of the callout view for these?

I have some pins on the map which I want of a lower opacity because they aren't sponsored listings.  Not to mention the default opacity is already a little too low for my purposes.

Am I stuck with subclassing or can I pull this off without violating any rules?  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MKAnnotationView is a subclass of UIView, so the alpha is available for you.